# In iphone, how to select desired size image from an image

Tags: iphone

Like in MS paint when we want to select portion of image we select rectangular box & drag over the image by click & holding left mouse key till the desired location.

How can we do the same functionality in iphone.

Plz help....

Answer (score 0):

You can use multitouch in an image view and touch two points to mark the corners of the selection rectangle.  You can then drag both fingers around to change the selection rectangle, and lock the selection when you lift one or both fingers.

Another alternative is to put the image in a scrollview.  Then zoom and pan the subview around inside the scrollview until the portion that just fits the full scrollview represents the selection.  You can put the control buttons outside the scrollview, or have them fade out and fade back in after some amount of time after the user has stopped moving the selection around.

Comment: Considering your first solution, i was also trying to do by same, but i need a dotted rectangle as far as the user drag over it.

Comment: You can use the two touches as diagonal corners to create the CGRect for the dotted rectangle, and redraw the dotted rectangle after every touches moved call.